# ¿Qué alternativas tengo a AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask

Siempre he trabajado con la clase `Asyntask` pero al día de hoy esta obsoleta.

> Default constructor in android.os.AsyncTask is deprecated

Además últimamente he visto que esta perjudicando algunas partes del código, he cambiado poco por poco un par de clases pero debido a que realizo diferentes funciones no me puedo dar el lujo de modificar absolutamente todas las clases donde utilizo el `Asyntask`, he buscando información al respecto pero siento temor de malograr mi código por cambiar algo en lo que siempre he venido trabajando, a continuación comparto un par de clases para que se comprenda mejor la forma en la que he trabajado durante todo este tiempo.

este es un contador en el carrito de compras.

```
public class ContadorProductos {
    public static class GetDataFromServerIntoTextView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
        public Context context;
        HttpResponse httpResponse;
        JSONArray jsonObject = null;
        String StringHolder = "";
        String contador_url = "http://pedidoslab.6te.net/consultas/contadorProdPedidos.php" + "?id_prefactura=" + Login.gIdPedido;

        public static Double gCount = 0.0;
        DecimalFormat formatoDecimal = new DecimalFormat("#");

        public GetDataFromServerIntoTextView(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(contador_url);

            try {
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                StringHolder = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {

                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(StringHolder);
                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONArray(0);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            try {

                JSONObject responseJSON = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(StringHolder));
                gCount = (responseJSON.getJSONArray("voto").getJSONObject(0).getDouble("count"));
                ObtenerProductos.tvCantProductos.setText(String.valueOf(formatoDecimal.format(gCount)));
                ObtenerCategorias.tvCantProd3.setText(String.valueOf(formatoDecimal.format(gCount)));
                //ObtenerAllProductos.tvCantProductos2.setText(String.valueOf(formatoDecimal.format(gCount)));

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

En esta clase elimino pedidos

```
public class EliminarDetPedido extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private final WeakReference<Context> context;
    public static boolean exitoDeleteProd = false;
    Double total = 0.00;

    public EliminarDetPedido(Context context) {
        this.context = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String registrar_url = "http://pedidoslab.6te.net/consultas/EliminarDetPedido.php" + "?id_det_prefactura=" + adapProdReport.lidDetPedido;

        String resultado;

        try {

            URL url = new URL(registrar_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            String idDetPrefactura = String.valueOf(adapProdReport.lidDetPedido);

            String data = URLEncoder.encode("id_det_prefactura", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(idDetPrefactura, "UTF-8");

            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }

            resultado = stringBuilder.toString();

            //if(equals("Record deleted successfully")) {
            exitoDeleteProd = true;
            total = TicketDatos.gTotal - adapProdReport.lDetMontoFinal;


            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    TicketDatos.subTotalReporte.setText(String.valueOf(total));
                }
            });


            //}else{
            //    exitoDeleteProd = false;
            //}

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.d("MiAPP", "Se ha utilizado una URL con formato incorrecto");
            resultado = "Se ha producido un ERROR";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("MiAPP", "Error inesperado!, posibles problemas de conexion de red");
            resultado = "Se ha producido un ERROR, comprueba tu conexion a Internet";
        }

        return resultado;
    }
}
```

Y esta seria la forma en la que he venido trabajando a lo largo del proyecto, partiendo de mi código que alternativas me podrían dar para cambiar la nomenclatura completa, me ayudaría mucho que me den algunos consejos sobre como implementar un nuevo código.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La documentación recomienda usar kotlin coroutines para todas las tareas asíncronas pero obviamente esto sólo funciona en kotlin. Si aún estás usando Java tu mejor opción es la librería [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) que ofrece features muy similares.

Por supuesto también hay opciones nativas y están en el package mencionado en la advertencia de la clase `AsyncTask`:

> This class was deprecated in API level 30.
> Use the standard java.util.concurrent or Kotlin concurrency utilities instead.

Esas APIs no son muy cómodas de usar pero, si te interesa, [esta](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/threading) es la guía de cómo hacerlo.

En cuanto a las peticiones http, la librería recomendada es [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit). En el [curso oficial de android](https://developer.android.com/courses/android-basics-kotlin/course) se explica como usarla pero te daré un ejemplo aplicado a tu caso.
Las dos clases que muestras podrían reemplazarse por sólo una interfaz que tenga un método por cada consulta que necesites. Luego retrofit usará la información de las anotaciones para generar automáticamente la implementación de esa interfaz.

```
public interface PedidosApi {
    @GET("contadorProdPedidos.php")
    Call<String> contarPedidos(@Query("id_prefactura") String idPedido);

    @GET("EliminarDetPedido.php")
    Call<String> eliminarPedido(@Query("id_det_prefactura") String idPedido);
}
```

Cada función debe tener la anotación del método http que le corresponda (GET, POST, etc) dentro de ella se escribe la url (sólo la parte que cambia, la baseUrl se indica en otro lado). Los query parameters se agregan con la anotación `@Query`.
El return type indica en que clase quieres convertir la respuesta pero, como las llamadas son asíncronas, necesitas envolverla con alguna clase observable. `Call` es la interfaz que trae retrofit pero también puedes usar las de otras librerías como LiveData o cualquiera de las clases observables de RxJava. En el ejemplo convierto la respuesta a `String` pero lo más normal es que sea a una de tus propias clases. Mas info en la [documentación](https://square.github.io/retrofit/).

En kotlin, puedes hacer que una función sea asíncrona simplemente agregándole la palabra `suspend`. De esta forma puedes definir el return type que quieras sin necesidad de ningún wrapper

```
// Mismo ejemplo pero en kotlin
interface PedidosApi {
    @GET("contadorProdPedidos.php")
    suspend fun contarPedidos(@Query("id_prefactura") idPedido: String): String

    @GET("EliminarDetPedido.php")
    suspend fun eliminarPedido(@Query("id_det_prefactura") idPedido: String): String
}
```

Comment: Excelente, gracias por responder, empezare a implementar esta nueva forma de programación, Gracias!!